# how to handle subpath for serverless static website using nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have a file named `example.com` in `sites-available` directory in nginx directory ubder `/etc` on ubuntu 18.04, which contains following codes:

```
server {

        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.comwww.example.ircom

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
.
.
.
.
```

Now how can I handle `example.com/FAQ` which has a totally different html file? Should I add another file named for example `example.com_faq` in `sites-available` and do the same for that or is it possible to handle it it the previously mentioned file? Tnx

Comment: No. You add a file at `/var/www/example.com/html/faq/index.html`

Comment: thanks a million, you can post your answer so I can mark it as the correct answer. @RichardSmith